# How to find out the storage consumption of a game on XBox One?

Tags: xbox-one, hard-drive

Games occupy more and more memory. XBox One amount of storage is usually limited to 500GB or 1TB. Users must manage their storage wisely or extend the storage hardware.

To manage wisely I would like to know how much storage the installed games occupy.

How to find out?

I tried to use the context menu on a games icon, where it is possible to close it (if it is running) or to delete it. Unfortunately there was no further info indicating the storage consumption.

Also I did not find the needed information in the settings area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found it. In the view with all the games (I guess it's "My Games and Apps" in English) there is a filter icon where you can choose orderings. The games can be ranked by storage consumption and in this mode the memory consumption of each game will be displayed at the corresponding icon.

Thanks Microsoft for the intuitive GUI design.